# Generating date data frame in R

Tags: r

I want to generate a data frame containing dates based on the date that I choose at the beginning as ReportDate:

```
ReportDate <- as.Date("2014-01-01")

date <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=60, ncol=1))

for(i in 1:60){

  date[i,1] = as.Date(ReportDate+i-1, origin="%Y-%m-%d")

}
```

but it gives me numeric values as output not date value. Please kindly tell me how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add integers to `Date` class objects directly:

```
ReportDate <- as.Date("2014-01-01")
DateDf <- data.frame(
  date=ReportDate+(0:59))
##
> head(DateDf)
        date
1 2014-01-01
2 2014-01-02
3 2014-01-03
4 2014-01-04
5 2014-01-05
6 2014-01-06
> str(DateDf)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ date: Date, format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-02" "2014-01-03" ...
```